# Sublime text 2 c++ error message (No Disk)

Tags: c++, windows

I am running sublime text 2 on windows 8 (The build system is on c++). When I run the program, an error message says g++.exe "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive l:." When I click continue another error message pops up saying cc1plus.exe (Same as before), When I click continue again, another error message pops up collect2.exe (Same as before). When I click continue for the third time It runs the code correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(My compiler is MinGW)
(My text editor is sublime text 2)
(My OS is Windows 8)

(I have installed MinGW before)

Here is my code: (If that matters)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

For clarification, after I am done with the error messages, the code RUNS and prints "Hello World!".

Comment: It's looking for the programs in the wrong drive it seems.

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your path environment variable.  Perhaps it refers to a drive you no longer have or a removable with no media.

Comment: No, my path environment variables are the same as on my laptop, and that works. However my laptop is running windows 7. Does that imply that maybe it is the OS that is breaking it?

Comment: Maybe I need to install sublime text 3, as it might be more compatible with windows 8, or is it MinGW that isn't compatible with windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a known problem with MinGW.  Specifically it is thought to be an issue in the GNU binutils gettext package.  There's a bug report on it over at SourceForge:

http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2108/

Unfortunately however, there doesn't appear to be an ETA for the fix.